# dealing pixel rounding for stacked responsive slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, slider

I am working on a [slider](http://robert-parker.me/slider/index.php) that is 10 sliders stacked on each other to make a whole picture. Every two seconds a random slice will slide left or right and if the slider is clicked it will move all the sliders to the same slide to make a whole picture.

Because the sliders are responsive I am having an issue with sub pixel rounding. As you resize the page or scroll you can occasionally get a white space between the different slides.

Is there A way I can remove this?

Comment: Have you tried to use <div> (with css background) instead of <img> ?

Comment: The defaults the purpose of a responsive image slider. The image and div are the same sizes. The issue is sub pixel rendering and not the image or the image size.